# Is EJBs lite managed by the container?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, war

I have to do a web service and a singleton that is running independently from the web service. So I decided to make it @Singleton EJB, without local or remote interfaces.

My question is whether it is possible the web service and the ejb to be in one and the same war, sharing one and the same libraries? And if so, is it possible (if using embedded ejbs) for the web container to manage the bean and start it if annotated as @Startup?

Answer (score 1):

An EJB is always managed by the container, and they can of course reside in the same WAR (in fact this is necessary to access it, if you don't have any remote interfaces)